# plotting complicating funtions

Tags: pgfplots, plot

Is it possible to plot the function `1/{1+\frac{1}{x}}` from 0 to 20 using `tikzpicture`, when I do it I just get a straight line

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}

    \addplot[smooth,samples=180,domain=0:0.5]{1/{1+{1/x}}};

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Sure it's possible: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[smooth,samples=180,domain=0.0001:20]{1/(1+(1/x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}` The result: http://i.imgur.com/DWYNRap.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

```
{1/{1+{1/x}}}
```

and you should use

```
{1/(1+(1/x))}
```

instead. A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[smooth,samples=180,domain=0.0001:20] {1/(1+(1/x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: for some reason x runs from -6 to 6. Is it because I am using other packages like \usepackage{hyperref,multicol,lipsum,geometry,titlesec,fancyhdr,amsmath,MnSymbol,wasysym,fleqn,mathtools}%

Comment: @user28952 Hard to tell from the information given. What do you get when pasting the *exact* same code I posted in a new fresh test document?

Comment: I still get the same result, x runs from -6 to 6. Even when using your exact code..

Comment: @user28952 which version of `pgfplots` are you using?

Comment: I don't know, How can I check that?

Comment: @user28952 Add `\listfiles` in the preamble of your document, compile it, and then check the `.log` file for the section `*File List*`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20782/discussion-between-user28952-and-gonzalo-medina).

Comment: My package is Package: pgfplots 2009/02/14 Version 1.2.2

Comment: Is the problem with package

Comment: @user28952 You have a very outdated package (5 years!); in my sytem (TeX Live2014), I am using `pgfplots.sty    2014/08/04 v1.11 Data Visualization (1.11-3-g4c99d7a)`. Please update your packages or, even better, your LaTeX system.

Comment: Just updated my latex system, it works fine now, thanks Gonzalo Medina.